# how to set dynamically created Radio buttons into a RadioGroup?

Tags: android

I have Radio buttons that are created dynamically.

```
                     LinearLayout linLayRoot = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_layout_root);
         RadioGroup radGp = new RadioGroup(this);
         linLayRoot.addView(radGp);

         for (String dir : dirArray)
         {

                LinearLayout linLayNew = new LinearLayout(this);
                linLayNew.setGravity(0x10);
                RadioButton radBut = new  RadioButton(this); /// <- this button does not work!
                radBut.setText("");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(dir);
                tv.setPadding(10, 0, 20, 0);
                ImageView ivs = new ImageView(this);

                linLayNew.addView(radBut);
                linLayNew.addView(tv);
                linLayNew.addView(ivs);

                radGp.addView(linLayNew);

         }

            RadioButton radBut1 = new  RadioButton(this); /// <- this button works!
            radBut1.setId(11);
            radBut1.setText("a1");
            radGp.addView(radBut1);

            RadioButton radBut2 = new  RadioButton(this); /// <- this button works!
            radBut2.setId(12);
            radBut2.setText("b2");
            radGp.addView(radBut2);

         radGp.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(checkedId) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });
```

But as you can see from the comments above, they don't really work, i.e. seems that they aren't binded to the radGp... maybe its because they are in a separate linlearlayout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your `RadioButtons` in a `List<RadioButton>` and you can check them then by using

```
    mRadioList.get(i).setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

the [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) has an [addView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) which takes a view as input. from here it seems you can add the LinearLayout as a child. and the RadioGroup is really a LinearLayout.

**UPDATE**

i checked the source of [RadioGroup.java](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/RadioGroup.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20RadioGroup&l=52&type=cs)

```
@Override
public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
    if (child instanceof RadioButton) {
        final RadioButton button = (RadioButton) child;
        if (button.isChecked()) {
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = true;
            if (mCheckedId != -1) {
                setCheckedStateForView(mCheckedId, false);
            }
            mProtectFromCheckedChange = false;
            setCheckedId(button.getId());
        }
    }

    super.addView(child, index, params);
}
```

this clearly shows that if we nest the radio then it will not work. 
so i guess, you have to go manual no other way.

Comment: see edit above, work without errors, but still allows users to select multiple buttons. :/

Comment: @Roger: i have edited my response. it seems we have to go manual after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to a List as Ovidiu suggests, but since they are not in a RadioGroup, except for setting checked the RadioButton at position i, you should setChecked(false) to all other RadioButtons.