# How to create dynamically radiobutton while parcing a csv file in android

Tags: android, csv, radio-button

I'm new to Android. I want to create a group of radiobuttons in application that I'm working on, but I want to define the number of radiobuttons from csv file or database. 
In a way that if I have two options in the csv file, show me 2 radiobutton and If I have 3 options in the csv file show me 3 radiobuttons.
How can i achieve this?

I'm using `eclipse`

Answer (score 1):

1) read the csv file:
[How to read csv file in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499351/how-to-read-csv-file-in-android)

2) in your application add for each option a radiobutton dynamically:
[how to set dynamically created Radio buttons into a RadioGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280306/how-to-set-dynamically-created-radio-buttons-into-a-radiogroup)

Answer (score 0):

Peace on you

to set dynamically created Radio buttons into a RadioGroupfor  I find this solution

http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/2012/08/05/creating-dynamic-views-in-android/

and to parce the csv file I've used this fonction

```
 private String[] loadArrayFromFileName(){

            String[] liste=null;
            String[] liste2=null;
            String liste3=null;
            int s=0;
        try {
        // Get input stream and Buffered Reader for our data file.
        InputStream is = FocusTow.this.getAssets().open("Test.csv"); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;

        //Read each line
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
         liste2=line.split("\n");
         for(int i=0; i< liste2.length;i++){
            if(s==0) {
                liste3=liste2[i];
                s=1;
                    }
                else liste3=liste3+","+liste2[i];
                }
                }
                liste=liste3.split(",");
                //Read each line

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return liste;
        }
```

and this is the code of my button listener

```
 mybutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 int j=0;

                 final String[] liste=loadArrayFromFileName();

                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub



         for( j=0;j<liste.length/2;j++){

         RadioButton radiobutton=new     RadioButton(getApplicationContext());

             radiobutton.setText(liste[j*2+1]);

             radioGroup.addView(radiobutton);




                                }
                            }
                       });
```

I hope this help u,
Thanks.